# Некорректно работает intersect

Tags: c#

Есть первый лист:

```
var tbBooks = (from Item in dbContext.Items
                                   join books in dbContext.Books
                                   on Item.Item_ID equals books.Book_ID
                                   where books.Book_ID < 3
                                   select new BooksOut
                                   {
                                       Name = Item.Name,
                                       Author = books.Author,
                                       ISBN = books.ISBN,
                                       Publisher = Item.Publisher,
                                       PublishingDate = Item.Publishing_date,
                                       ExpireTerm = Item.Expire_term,
                                       Book_ID = books.Book_ID
                                   }).ToList();
```

и есть второй лист:

```
  var testBook = (from Item in dbContext.Items
                                    join books in dbContext.Books
                                    on Item.Item_ID equals books.Book_ID
                                    where books.Book_ID > 1
                                    select new BooksOut
                                    {
                                        Name = Item.Name,
                                        Author = books.Author,
                                        ISBN = books.ISBN,
                                        Publisher = Item.Publisher,
                                        PublishingDate = Item.Publishing_date,
                                        ExpireTerm = Item.Expire_term,
                                        Book_ID = books.Book_ID
                                    }).ToList();
```

Мне нужно найти пересечение этих листов и я делаю это вот так:

```
var TestList = testBook.Intersect(tbBooks).ToList();
```

Но `TestList` оказывается пустым.

В чем же нюанс? Или как мне найти пересечение двух листов? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: - Проверьте, что последовательности `testBook` и `tbBooks` **действительно содержат элементы** после выполнения запроса. Если это так, то, скорее всего, проблема в том, как вы определяете операцию равенства.

- Я думаю, что для элементов вашей коллекции у вас не реализованы кастомные методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode`, а значит, сравнение элементов выполняется по ссылкам, а не *"по смыслу"* - в вашем случае, скорее всего, просто по `Book_ID`.

- Поскольку `LINQ` к БД создает новые объекты на каждый запрос, то все элементы будут разными по ссылкам, и, как следствие, `Intersect` вернет ∅.

Comment: testBook и tbBooks действительно содержат элементы. 
Как тогда можно найти пересечение листов?

Comment: @Flash См. второй пункт прошлого комментария - либо реализуйте логически верные `Equals() + GetHashCode()`, либо напишите собственный `IEqualityComparer<T>` и используйте его в методе `Intersect`.

Comment: А как работает сам intersect? Сравнивает хешкоды  или по equals?

Comment: скорее всего через `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value1, value2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо [Котик_ хочет_кушать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) за помощь

Сделал свой IEqualityComparer:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<BooksOut>
    {


        public bool Equals(BooksOut b1, BooksOut b2)
            {
                if (b1.Book_ID == b2.Book_ID
                                    & b1.ISBN == b2.ISBN)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }


        public int GetHashCode(BooksOut bx)
            {
                int hCode = bx.Book_ID ^ Convert.ToInt32(bx.ISBN);
                return hCode.GetHashCode();
            }

    }
```

Comment: У вас ошибка - логическое "и" обозначается как `&&`, а не `&`.

Comment: почему сразу опечатка, может так задумано, хотя маловероятно канеш, но возможно

Comment: Ну тут смысла нету использовать логическое И вместо условного И, а так да, очепятка